# Big O occurring in inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

It is well known that if $f$ and $g$ are real valued functions defined on some domains, we write $f(x)=O(g(x))$ if there exists a constant $C \in \mathbb R_{>0}$ such that $|f(x)|  \leq C |g(x)|$ for all $x$ in the domain of definition of both functions.

In some places, I have seen a statement such as $f(x) \geq  g(x)+ O(h(x))$. What does this statement mean?

Comment: It should mean that $f(x)\ge g(x)+u(x)$ where $u(x)=O(h(x))$.

Comment: So here $u(x)$ is some function such that $u(x)=O(h(x))$?

Comment: Yes.$\vphantom{dummy}$